# Laravel how to convert data into an object

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I have the following code under my edit function of my project:

```
$bankAcc = BankingAccount::find($id)->where('id', $id)->with('userprinciple')->with('banks')->first();
```

When I `dd` the `$bankAccount` variable I get the following results:

```
BankingAccount {#1590 ▼
      #fillable: array:8 [▶]
      #table: "banking_accounts"
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: array:1 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:14 [▶]
      #original: array:14 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:2 [▶]
      #touches: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
```

But I only want the data under the attributes in an object. So that I can for example do this in my blade:

```
{{ $bankAcc->userprinciple->principle }}
```

I keep getting various errors as I have been trying - mostly trying to show property of non-object. So how do I convert that data into and object?

Comment: you don't have to do anything; what you're describing is the default behavior of Eloquent. `trying to show property of non-object` means that you're trying to access related data is doesn't exist: userprinciple. Make sure that `userprinciple` exists for that record

Comment: @Ali the userprinciple is set in my relations and I have a pivot table. Everything saves to the database, it is just when I try on my edit page to access the data that I get the error

Comment: Just do `$bankAcc = BankingAccount::find($id);`  
and `$bankAcc->userprinciple` will be accessible if its a has many you will have to do `$bankAcc->userprinciple->first()->principal` etc